# Merge one subject observations to all others

Tags: r, merge

I'm attempting to remove a subject from the data set and then subsequently merge them in with the others so that their values at each time point can be compared to everyone else.

This is what the data looks like:

```
subject <- rep(1:5, each = 20)
seconds <- rep(1:20, times = 20)
variable <- rnorm(n = subject, mean = 20, sd = 10)
d <- data.frame(subject, seconds, variable)
```

Then, I am removing subject four from the data and trying to merge them back to compare them to each of the other subjects:

```
four <- subset(d, subject == 4)
d2 <- subset(d, subject != 4)
```

I've tried this but the problem is that it repeats each of the seconds 4 times for each merge:

```
merge(d2, four, by = "seconds")
```

Is there a way to get an exact merge of each individual relative to subject 4?

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code comes from the fact that only subjects `4` have values that satisfy `seconds == 4`. See:

```
subject <- rep(1:5, each = 20)
seconds <- rep(1:20, each = 20)
d <- data.frame(subject, seconds)
with(d, table(subject, seconds))
       seconds
subject  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
      1 20  0  0  0  0 20  0  0  0  0 20  0  0  0  0 20  0  0  0  0
      2  0 20  0  0  0  0 20  0  0  0  0 20  0  0  0  0 20  0  0  0
      3  0  0 20  0  0  0  0 20  0  0  0  0 20  0  0  0  0 20  0  0
      4  0  0  0 20  0  0  0  0 20  0  0  0  0 20  0  0  0  0 20  0
      5  0  0  0  0 20  0  0  0  0 20  0  0  0  0 20  0  0  0  0 20
```

Since you are merging on seconds, and for all entries in `four`, seconds equals four, the output of merge is correct, i.e. you would expect an empty table.

If you change the ordering, the problem will not occur.

```
subject <- rep(1:20, each = 5)
seconds <- rep(1:20, each = 20)
d <- data.frame(subject, seconds)

four <- subset(d, subject == 4)
d2 <- subset(d, subject != 4)

newdf <- merge(d2, four, by = "seconds")
head(newdf)
  seconds subject.x subject.y
1       1         1         4
2       1         1         4
3       1         1         4
4       1         1         4
5       1         1         4
6       1         1         4
```

Where you see that now we can find subjects in x and in y, i.e. the left and right dataframe handed over to `merge`.

---

A comment: what you are after sounds more like reshaping your data, but you still need to figure out what to do with your duplicates. To give you an idea:

```
library(reshape2)
d$ind <- factor(d$subject==4, labels = c("four", "not four"))
out <- dcast(d, seconds ~ ind, fun.aggregate = function(x) x[1], value.var = "variable")
head(out)
  seconds      four  not four
1       1 20.836195 16.539739
2       2 15.923540 11.534704
3       3  1.250495 12.992153
4       4 25.127817 31.510210
5       5  8.990819  8.030607
6       6 21.783900 38.300430
```

This will take the first value whenever there is a duplicate.

Comment: Thank you. I actually see that I had an error in my example data (in the seconds column, as you pointed out). I've edited the original post to correct for that. The issue I am having is the repeating of each of the seconds 4 times when doing the merge..

Comment: What would you expect? There are multiple entries in your data. If you don't want to have them, you can drop duplicates.

Comment: Okay, I can certainly drop duplicates but with such a large data set I am working with, I wasn't sure if there was a way to make the code more streamlined and get exactly what I was asking for.

Comment: I am sure there is, but the data that you are showing here is just repeating itself quite frequently, so it necessarily contains duplicates. Can you show us an example of your real data?

Comment: @user3585829 I have added a small code snippet that might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. The original data looks similar to this. What I'm trying to get is a data frame that basically has the comparison for subject one to four at each second/time point and then subject two to four at each second/time point, etc. If that makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183324/discussion-between-coffeinjunky-and-user3585829).